# How to find categorical outlier/noise rows in bigquery window

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sliding-window

How would i detect outlier rows in bigquery and mark rows as outliers. For each row, I want to look at 5 rows before and 5 rows after and see if the value changed.

Here is an example of a table.

[image]

In this table I would want the highlighted rows to have some boolean flag to say outlier because the rows only change for a brief second. However, when it changes from id 19 to 5, that is okay (assuming that is a continued change). Basically I am trying to remove glitches where it just changes from one user id to another for 2 rows, so i want to mark those rows with some flag. I was thinking of doing this in bigquery by looking at lag rows and lead rows in a given window (over a partition), but am not sure if i am on the right path.

This isn't a typical "outlier" case as all rows should have the same value except for the glitches and it is more of a categorical variable, albeit a number.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to create a lag function that looks for these switches and then if it is a switch changes them, the problem is that if a highlighted row switches, that could impact the calculation for the next row (like dominos)

Comment: so my thought was to look at subsequences that are short